# Memoizing cheap side-results

Tags: haskell, memoization

I'd like to memoize a function with type, say,

```
f :: Int -> Integer
```

Which I could easily do, using e.g. the [MemoCombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators) package, as such:

```
f_ = Memo.integral f
```

However, when given a pair `(x, f x)`, there are lots of other points for which calculating `f` is easy given `f x`:

```
freebies :: (Int, Integer) -> [(Int, Integer)]
```

But given a point `x'`, it is not cheap to calculate some `x` for which `elem x' . map fst $ freebies (x, f x)`. So I'd like to store these additional `(x', y')` pairs as they become available, so that later, `f x'` can be calculated efficiently.

My question is, what is a good way to memoize such a function?

Comment: What kind of function `f` are we talking about? It seems to basically be recursive, or is it computing incremental approximations? There's no general solution to this problem unless the relation between `x` and `x'` is known.

Comment: Is your quetion about how to calculate f⁻¹(y) by memorization of all calculated f(x)?

Comment: dfelmstr: Well my starting point is that I have both `f` and `freebies`, but `f` is not recursive so calculating `f x'` doesn't involve calculating `f x` even if `x'` is in `map fst $ freebies (x, f x)`.

Comment: nist: No, I want to calculate all of `f x1`, `f x2`, ..., `f xn`, but it'd be nice if `f xj` didn't to the expensive calculation part again if it was already a freebie from `f xi` for some `i<j`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so using *pure* memoization, you need to find a way to map the `x`s of your freebies back to the point that generated it.  If you want to think about the capabilities of pure memoization, don't think of it as a cache table that gets updated; rather, think of it as a data dependency graph that gets gradually simplified.  You need a way for the freebies to point to what calculates them.

Supposing you had that:

```
-- Representative k finds a k', where it is easy to calculate
-- k from (k')'s value (this calculation is the Value -> Value
-- function)
-- There should be multiple (k')'s per k; and representative k' 
-- on one of those should return (k', const v), where v is the
-- value.
representative :: Key -> (Key, Value -> Value)
```

Then you could memoize:

```
table = memoKey go
    where
    go k = let (k', vf) = representative k in
           vf (table k')
```

where `memoKey` is a memoizer for `Key`.

Keep in mind that `Value` could be a more complex type that has the information necessary to compute the freebies, and then you can throw away the extra information for final user.

If you can't invert `freebies` into `representative`'s form, then I think you are out of luck for *pure* memoization strategies.  This is because if you did it the way you suggest, the value in the table of freebies would depend on what was evaluated *first*, and that is a no-no in pure Haskell.  (Even if you know the values will be the same, a pure memoization strategy can't even be capable of depending on the evaluation order)

You could alternatively use an approach with explicit state holding the table, or an `unsafePerformIO`-based impure memo table.